# Git bash folder location under windows 7

Tags: git, bash

I have installed git bash and create few folders using git bash. I wanted to search over Windows explorer but don't know exactly where these folders are actually created

Can please some one help me

Answer (score 0):

`start .` from command line will open Windows Explorer in your current working directory. It works both in `cmd` and Git Bash.

By default Git is installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\` bu you can change it at installation time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cygpath` program to convert from POSIX names to Win32 names.

For example, to know the full name of the current directory:

```
$ cygpath -wa .
```